# PHP: Number of all elements in an array

Tags: php

Is there a way to find out how many value-elements are in one array in all nesting levels?

I want to find out how many are in `$_REQUEST` to give out a warning if the limit dictated by the `max_input_vars` directive is nearly reached?

I want to count only the real values, so **array-elements should not be counted if they are another array** (see 
http://pastebin.com/QAKxxqJf)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php - look at the options for `$mode`

Comment: @rubo77 I recently had the same problem. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19096811/1873446) to know how I solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution for PHP <= 5.2

```
/**
 * Counts only the real values, so array-elements
 * are not counted if they are another array.
 *
 * @param array $array
 * @return int
 * @author Muslim Idris
 */
function count_recursive($array) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($array as $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) $count += count_recursive($v);
            else $count++;
    }
    return $count;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

use: `count($array_name, COUNT_RECURSIVE);`

as `count` method takes a second argument which is the mode. `int` `COUNT_NORMAL` or `COUNT_RECURSIVE`

Comment: I think this is not completely correct, because a recursive count also counts keys into the total, see: http://pastebin.com/QAKxxqJf

Comment: Substract count from count recursive you will get the magic going. In  Advanced cases you will need to do some if and foreach tricks :-)

Comment: This is not the correct answer! `max_input_vars` doesen't count the subarray containers while `count($a, 1)` does (although `count($a, COUNT_RECURSIVE);` is a good thing in general ;) )

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_walk_recursive` to count all elements that are not of type `array` or `object`:

```
$count = 0;
array_walk_recursive($a, function($v) use(&$count) {
    if(!is_object($v)) ++$count;      //or if(is_string($v))
});
```

Comment: Why do you need `if(!is_array($v) && !is_object($v))`? with just plain `++$count;` I get the same result for `$count` (tested with the multidimensional array `$_REQUEST`)

Comment: so it ignores object values. If you had for example `3 => new foo()` in your array it will count that as an element. You could just check if it is a `string` if you want. It depends on the case. However I think you do not need `!is_array($v)`. Please confirm and I will remove that validation from my answer.

Comment: i tested it, you only need `if(!is_object($v))` or all objects would be counted as one element each, not though the variables inside the object, they are ignored all the time.

Comment: @rubo77 thanks. Seeing your pastebin link I would check for `string` type instead. However it is best to mantain `object` validation in my answer for others users in the future since it is more generic

Comment: [When was function use closures implemented in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411631/when-was-function-use-closures-implemented-in-php)

Comment: closures are implemented in PHP 5.3 so your solution is effective, but since this is not possible in PHP 5.2 I have to use muslim-idris' solution

Comment: you did not specified PHP version in your question so last stable version was taken in account when answering this question

Comment: sure, but I read somewhere, I have to enter the question that solve MY problem. I have to administer different php versions starting from 5.2

Answer (score 0):

I cannot use [count($_REQUEST, COUNT_RECURSIVE)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php), so I used:

```
function count_recursive($array) {
  $count = 0;
  foreach ($array as $id => $_array) {
    if (is_array ($_array)) $count += count_recursive ($_array);
    else $count += 1;
  }
  return $count;
} 
$num=count_recursive($_REQUEST);
$max=ini_get('max_input_vars');
$debug=true;
if($debug and $max - $num < 50) {
  echo "Warning:Number of requests ($num) is near the value of max_input_vars:$max";
}
```

*(although there is still a strange thing is on my testing server, but thats another question: [why is the number of elements in $_REQUEST smaller than the limit i set by max_input_vars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094866/why-is-the-number-of-elements-in-request-smaller-than-the-limit-i-set-by-max-i) and maybe a bug in PHP)*

Answer (score -2):

check following link for all option of using count function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php