# why is the number of elements in $_REQUEST smaller than the limit i set by max_input_vars?

Tags: php

a strange thing is on my testing server: I set `max_input_vars` to just `100` and sent a huge request with `over 100` elements

I used:

```
$num=count($_REQUEST, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
$max=ini_get('max_input_vars');
if($max - $num<50) {
              die('Number of requests ('.$num.') near the maximum allowed value of max_input_vars:'.ini_get('max_input_vars'));
}
```

but I get the error

> Number of requests `(90)` near the maximum allowed value of max_input_vars:100

why just 90? shouldnt it be 100 then or 99?

I get 240 vars in $_REQUEST if I set a higher limit, to be precise:

- $_GET: 1
- $_POST: 239
- $_COOKIE: 1

Comment: Are you sure you're sending over 100 _uniquely named_ input fields? `max_input_vars` does not account for unique names (if I send `field_name` twice, it will count as 2 input vars), but they will only be put in `$_REQUEST` once (with preference towards the more recent).

Comment: yes, I am sure, If I set a higher limit, I get 240 with the same count and the same repuest

Comment: Do you have any arrays in your `$_REQUEST` values?

Comment: Yes I have many arrays in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

max_input_vars doesen't count the subarray containers while count($a, COUNT_RECURSIVE) does, so you have to use a recursive loop instead:

```
$count = 0;
array_walk_recursive($_REQUEST, function($v) use(&$count) {
    if(!is_object($v)) ++$count;      //or if(is_string($v))
});
```