# When was function use closures implemented in PHP?

Tags: php, closures

I couldn't find the section in the PHP manual that explains `use`

I have the code

```
$num = 0;
array_walk_recursive($_REQUEST, function($mValue) use (&$num){
           $num++;
        });
```

and my Eclipse complains:

```
Parser error "'{' expected in compound-statement.
```

So I guess this was implemented in some PHP version.

Comment: "I couldn't find the section in the PHP manual that explains use" --- have you checked an anonymous function reference page?

Comment: See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#~Changelog

Comment: @mario: that's interesting - what `#~Changelog` means?

Comment: @zerkms It's a text search anchor; very much *non-standardized*. There were some whatwg discussions on such features, which however didn't go anywhere. So I made a [userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/119759).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous functions/closures and the `use` language construct were implemented in version 5.3.0

@see changelog: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: And it would be nice if it was a reference to the documentation in the answer

Comment: Hi @zerkms, just beat me to it!